# Merge в ветку, которая имела изменения

Tags: git, merge, branch

Я сделал новую ветку B от ветки master (M). В ветке B сделал изменения в файле F. Пока делал изменения в файле F ветки B, в ветке master добавилось несколько коммитов. И теперь, когда я из ветки master делаю git merge B, я получаю конфликты в файлах, которые были изменены в ветке master, пока я работал в своей ветке B.

Как мне, когда я делаю git merge, учитывать только изменения, которые я сделал в ветке B? Можно ли сказать гиту, какие файлы оставить из ветки master при merge?

Comment: Когда вы делаете git merge B, то уже учитываются только изменения, которые вы сделали в ветке B. *"Можно ли сказать гиту, какие файлы оставить из ветки master при merge?"* - Это можно будет сделать при разруливании конфликтов.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 0):

Каждый конфликт - это то что не удалось разрешить автоматически. То есть по каждому конфликту git предлагает разрешать его в отдельном инструменте, IDE, текстовом реадкторе. И там для каждого файла выбирать какую версию применить - вашей ветки или текущей. Если для всех файлов надо выбирать одинаковый вариант - тогда можно сделать автоматически

```
git merge branch -X ours
```

или

```
git merge branch -X theirs
```

Первое - это всегда выбирать изменения из вашей ветки, второе - из ветки в которую сливаете изменения.

Comment: `второе - из ветки в которую сливаете изменения.` - ИЗ которой сливаете изменения

Comment: Не стоит советовать такие потенциально опасные вещи как -X ours/theirs новичку.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Держать от него в секрете команды? Хитро хитро. А в плане предостережений -  в гите откатить можно вообще все, так что нет ничего фатального ни в каких командах